System "go back" button closes whole application in Flutter
Hello everyone I am having a problem with handling the back gesture (back button) on Android in my Flutter App. For example, I have a screen pushed with the pushNamed function of Navigator (the Login Screen is pushed from the Welcome Screen). In that screen I want the app to go back to the previous screen but instead, the app closes. Here is the code.
Router class
class AppRouter {
  Route<dynamic>? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
    switch (routeSettings.name) {
      case '/login':
        return PageRouteBuilder(
            settings: routeSettings,
            pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
              return const LoginScreen();
            },
            // Pass this to make popUntil(), pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(), works
            transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
            reverseTransitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 450),
            transitionsBuilder: (_, a, __, c) => SlideTransition(
                position: Tween<Offset>(
                  begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0), // From bottom
                  end: Offset.zero,
                ).animate(
                  CurvedAnimation(
                    parent: a,
                    curve: Curves.easeInOutCubicEmphasized,
                  ),
                ),
                child: c));
      default:
        return _materialRoute(const WelcomeScreen());
    }
  }

  static Route<dynamic> _materialRoute(Widget view) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => view);
  }
}

main.dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
      SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge,
    );

    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(430, 932),
        minTextAdapt: true,
        splitScreenMode: true,
        builder: (_, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            home: Navigator(
              key: navigatorKey,
              onGenerateRoute: AppRouter().onGenerateRoute,
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}

Welcome screen
class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const WelcomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _WelcomeScreenState();
  }
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/login');
                  },
                  child: const Text('Continue with E-Mail'),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Login screen
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoginScreenState();
  }
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: true,
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) => print('onPopInvoked didPop? $didPop'),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 0.09.sh,
            leadingWidth: 70,
            leading: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/welcome');
                },
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/icons/back-in-circle.svg',
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light
                      ? colorBlack
                      : null,
                ),
              ),
            )),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Text("Login screen")
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Have already added the following line to AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...

    <application
        ...
        <activity
            ...
            android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true">

UPDATE: View the GIFs for reference
This is how it is currently: https://giphy.com/gifs/4uPLXp98w8toVO6RWQ/fullscreen
This is the expected behaviour: https://giphy.com/gifs/uN64gQHuPJR6YLYsIJ/fullscreen

You are using pushReplacementNamed in the LoginScreen instead of pop.
pushReplacementNamed replaces the current route with the new route. This is why the app is closed instead of going back to the Welcome Screen.

Changed it but that does not solve the issue at all - because that pushReplacementNamed is only handled on the button click and the issue is with the system "go back" button and not the applications' go back button.
We want to make this work with the system "go-back" i.e. the default go-back button from the device.

Just added two GIFs so it is more clear where the issue is.

Were you able to check the issue?
